# Resize or scale displaymath environment

Tags: math-mode, minipage, scaling, resize

I would like to resize the two schemes I made with the `displaymath` environment. However, I cannot find anything helpful. I'd like to fit both schemes into one page.

My code is the following:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{minipage}[c]{1\textwidth}
            \centering

    \begin{center}
    \begin{displaymath}
        \text{Diagnoses } 
         \begin{cases}
            \text{Diagnoses}_1 & 
            \begin{cases}
                \text{Codes}_{1} &
                \begin{cases}
                    \text{Code}_{11}\\
                    \text{Code}_{12}\\  
                    \text{Code}_{13}\\\quad\quad\vdots\\ 
                    \text{Code}_{1Ncodes} &
                \end{cases}\\   
                \text{Code Events}_{1} &
                \begin{cases}
                    \text{Events}_{11}\\
                    \text{Events}_{12}\\    
                    \text{Events}_{13}\\\quad\quad\vdots\\ 
                    \text{Events}_{1Ncodes} &
                \end{cases}\\   

            \end{cases}
            \\
            \text{Diagnoses}_2\\
            \text{Diagnoses}_3\\\quad\quad\vdots\\ 
            \text{Diagnoses}_{Npatients}
        \end{cases}
    \end{displaymath}
    \end{center}

    \footnotetext{ ${Diagnoses}_i$   where  i=1..Npatients\\ ${Codes}_ i$ where i = 1..Npatients \\ ${Code}_{ij}$ where  i = 1..Npatients,    j = 1..Ncodes \\  ${Events}_{ij}$   where i = 1..Npatients,    j = 1..Ncodes}

    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Diagnoses structures per CRG and year extracted from original databases.}
    \label{scheme-diag_ppal/Secondary-final-db}

\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}[c]{1\textwidth}
        \centering
    \begin{center}

     \begin{displaymath}
    \text{Procedures }\begin{cases}
    \text{Procedures}_1 & 
    \begin{cases}
        \text{codes}_{1} &
        \begin{cases}
            \text{code}_{11}\\
            \text{code}_{12}\\  
            \text{code}_{13}\\\quad\quad\vdots\\ 
            \text{code}_{1Ncodes} &
        \end{cases}\\   
        \text{Code Events}_{1} &
        \begin{cases}
            \text{Events}_{11}\\
            \text{Events}_{12}\\    
            \text{Events}_{13}\\\quad\quad\vdots\\ 
            \text{Events}_{1Ncodes} &
        \end{cases}\\   

    \end{cases}
    \\
    \text{Procedures}_2\\
    \text{Procedures}_3\\\quad\quad\vdots\\ 
    \text{Procedures}_{Npatients}
    \end{cases}
    \end{displaymath}
\end{center}


    \footnotetext{ ${Diagnoses}_i$   where i=1..Npatients\\ ${Codes}_ i$ where i = 1..Npatients \\ ${Code}_{ij}$ where i = 1..Npatients,    j = 1..Ncodes \\  ${Events}_{ij}$  where i = 1..Npatients,    j = 1..Ncodes}

\end{minipage}
\caption{Procedures structures per CRG and year extracted from original databases.}
\label{scheme-proc_ppal/Secondary-final-db}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vastly simplify your code: the `minipage`s are not needed, nor the `center` environments.

Also, a `figure` environment can contain any number of `\caption` commands, so you just need one (and definitely no `[H]` option).

Apply a `\footnotesize` command as soon as the `figure` environment starts.

I also fixed the appearance of text subscripts to be upright.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\footnotesize
\begin{displaymath}
\text{Diagnoses }
\begin{cases}
  \text{Diagnoses}_1 &
  \begin{cases}
    \text{Codes}_{1} &
    \begin{cases}
      \text{Code}_{11}\\
      \text{Code}_{12}\\  
      \text{Code}_{13}\\
      \quad\quad\vdots\\ 
      \text{Code}_{1\text{Ncodes}}
    \end{cases}\\   
    \text{Code Events}_{1} &
    \begin{cases}
      \text{Events}_{11}\\
      \text{Events}_{12}\\    
      \text{Events}_{13}\\
      \quad\quad\vdots\\ 
      \text{Events}_{1\text{Ncodes}}
    \end{cases}\\
  \end{cases}\\
  \text{Diagnoses}_2\\
  \text{Diagnoses}_3\\\quad\quad\vdots\\ 
  \text{Diagnoses}_{\text{Npatients}}
\end{cases}
\end{displaymath}

\medskip\footnoterule

Diagnoses$_i$ where $i=1..\text{Npatients}$\\
Codes$_i$ where $i=1..\text{Npatients}$\\
Code$_{ij}$ where $i=1..\text{Npatients}$, $j=1..\text{Ncodes}$\\
Events$_{ij}$ where $i=1..\text{Npatients}$, $j=1..\text{Ncodes}$

\caption{Diagnoses structures per CRG and year extracted from original databases.}
\label{scheme-diag_ppal/Secondary-final-db}

\begin{displaymath}
\text{Procedures }
\begin{cases}
  \text{Procedures}_1 &
  \begin{cases}
    \text{codes}_{1} &
    \begin{cases}
      \text{code}_{11}\\
      \text{code}_{12}\\  
      \text{code}_{13}\\
      \quad\quad\vdots\\ 
      \text{code}_{1\text{Ncodes}}
    \end{cases}\\   
    \text{Code Events}_{1} &
    \begin{cases}
      \text{Events}_{11}\\
      \text{Events}_{12}\\    
      \text{Events}_{13}\\
      \quad\quad\vdots\\ 
      \text{Events}_{1\text{Ncodes}}
    \end{cases}\\
  \end{cases}\\
  \text{Procedures}_2\\
  \text{Procedures}_3\\
  \quad\quad\vdots\\ 
  \text{Procedures}_{\text{Npatients}}
\end{cases}
\end{displaymath}

\medskip\footnoterule

Diagnoses$_i$ where $i=1..\text{Npatients}$\\
Codes$_i$ where $i=1..\text{Npatients}$\\
Code$_{ij}$ where $i=1..\text{Npatients}$, $j=1..\text{Ncodes}$\\
Events$_{ij}$ where $i=1..\text{Npatients}$, $j=1..\text{Ncodes}$

\caption{Procedures structures per CRG and year extracted from original databases.}
\label{scheme-proc_ppal/Secondary-final-db}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I see, thanks so much @egreg, but I would also like to get these horizontal lines which I deployed above the "notefoot" of each scheme.

Comment: @Javiss Just add `\footnoterule` after `\medskip` as in the edited answer

Comment: nice @egreg! thanks a lot! I will be aware next time! Just learned how to deploy figures in the correct way.